# Table with sticky column - Issue with cell size

Tags: html, css

I have a table that can slide left or right when the screen is narrow enough.  The first column is positioned absolute so that it is always visible.

Is it possible to make the cells in the first column maintain the size of the cells in the other columns?  I am not sure how to achieve this while keeping the first column frozen.

Here is a fiddle to my code:  http://jsfiddle.net/ta945/

Here's the HTML and CSS

HTML:

```
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="sticky">Name</th>
            <th>Helpful Services</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>URL</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="sticky">First Name</td>
            <td>Math</td>
            <td>CO</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>123-456-7890</td>
            <td>http://somewhere.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="sticky">Second Name</td>
            <td>Reading</td>
            <td>NY</td>
            <td>New York City</td>
            <td>123-456-7890</td>
            <td>http://somewhere.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="sticky">Third Name</td>
            <td>Art</td>
            <td>IL</td>
            <td>Chicago</td>
            <td>123-456-7890</td>
            <td>http://somewhere.com</td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td class="sticky">Four Name</td>
            <td>Programming</td>
            <td>IL</td>
            <td>Chicago</td>
            <td>123-456-7890</td>
            <td>http://somewhere.com</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

table {
  border-collapse: seperate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin-left: 5em;
}

thead, tbody, tr {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

th {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  background-color: #676767;
  color: #FFFFFF
}

td {
  padding: 2px 4px;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.sticky {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: auto;
  margin-left: 9px;
}
```

Comment: What is your desired effect? Seems like there might be an easier way to do it. I can't tell at all based on the way my browser renders it.

Comment: I was thinking for a mobile device that the table could slide left or right while keeping the first column frozen in place so that it is always visible.  I have that, but the cells in the first column are much smaller then the cells in the rest of the column.  I think it is because of the position:absolute, but am not sure how else to keep the column frozen if I remove that.

Comment: I have something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ta945/5/ , but it's ugly. Needs quite a lot of work to be acceptable...

Comment: Call me crazy, but what would happen if you simply specified a width for `td.sticky` (or `tr td:first-child` which seems equivalent) and set the `min-width` for the whole table to the same value. Wouldn't the browser take care of this for you?

Comment: @Two-Bit Alchemist Do you mean to set the min-width for td.sticky and the table to something like `min-width: 50px;`?  I tried this but I'm not sure I follow what you mean.  The height of the frozen cells is not the same as the other cells in the row.  Can it be set so that height of the frozen cell is the same as the other cells in the same row, just like a table normally displays?

Comment: I was thinking [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/9cPLe/).

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I see what you mean but I am thinking is like the Bootstrap responsive table, only with the first column frozen.  Check out the table here that scrolls left & right at smaller screen widths: http://anvoz.github.io/bootstrap-tldr/#tables